# Setting the Default Value of a Slicer on power bi

Tags: powerbi

I want to set default filter of this week to slicer.However ,every answer use the option list.

```
if(weeknum(now())=weeknum([mydate]),"current week",[mydate]).
```

I selected the bar and choose start date with end date  to  filter date.On the previous way it's work on option-list but not on bar. 
Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about this in two ways.

Create a slicer which is used to calculate the week:

```
ThisWeek = if(weeknum(now) = weeknum(date), "Yes", "No")
```

It is however worth noting that if you have a data set that contains dates over several years it could show more data than required. In this case I would create the below column and use a Slicer based off of that.

```
ThisWeek = if(weeknum(now) = weeknum(date && year(now) = year(date), "Yes", "No")
```

You can then setup the interactions to filter your date slicer so the default range would be set as the value defined within "ThisWeek"

Alternately you could create a page filter which only shows records for this week. Again you would use the same format as above however there would be no need for the slicer.